# How to redirect all files to index using .htaccess ReWriteEngine?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website, I need to display ONLY the home page instead of an actual URL being request (website is work in progress).

Any urls within that domain should be rewritten to index.html and only index.html should be visible in the entire website.

How to write the rules in my current script?
Notes: I am not interested on the SEO impact.

```
RewriteEngine on

# SECURITY : Directory Listing denied
options -indexes

# UTILITY : Redirect WebMail
redirect permanent /email http://www.example.com:2095/3rdparty/roundcube/index.php?



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have tried this RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L] but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
# SECURITY : Directory Listing denied
options -indexes
# by default load index.html 
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine on

# UTILITY : Redirect WebMail
RewriteRule ^email/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:2095/3rdparty/roundcube/index.php? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule !^(index\.html|.+?\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf|ico))?$ / [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: it did not work with any existing .html files... so I was able to access them and no redirection occurred. Thanks for your support.

Comment: ok based on your comment I've modified it to make it work for any other `.html` file also.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem with the following code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.html [L]

Try this